# /etc/group is void, raspberry works fine however

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, corrupt

Well, for an unknown reason the file `/etc/group` has been cleared during a ssh session last week. As I manage ssh with `allowgroups sshusers` I could no more log in, but could however use the current session to modify `sshd_config` with `allowusers` so I can still log in.

I first though the problem came from command `sudo addgroup user group` I entered instead of `sudo adduser user group`, because group was void just after this. But after retrying it seems both commands are equivalent. So to be completely honnest, `/etc/group` is not void but contains only the last created groups. After those commands :

```
$ sudo adduser crashdebug 
$ sudo adduser helloworld testing
$ sudo addgroup helloworld testing
$ sudo deluser helloworld testing
```

I got this (first line is blank) :

```
$ sudo cat /etc/group

crashdebug:x:1000:
testing:x:1001:helloworld
```

And :

```
$ groups pi && groups crashdebug && groups helloworld
pi : crashdebug
crashdebug : crashdebug
helloworld : groups: cannot find name for group ID 1004
1004 testing
$ id pi && id crashdebug && id helloworld
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(crashdebug) groups=1000(crashdebug)
uid=1005(crashdebug) gid=1000(crashdebug) groups=1000(crashdebug)
uid=1004(helloworld) gid=1004 groups=1004,1001(testing)
$ getent group
crashdebug:x:1000:
testing:x:1001:helloworld
```

Some of `/etc/passwd` including all created users :

```
$ cat /etc/passwd |  grep /bin/bash
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
nix:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/nix:/bin/bash
autossh:x:1002:1002:,,,:/home/autossh:/bin/bash
adminmiaou:x:1003:1003:,,,:/home/adminmiaou:/bin/bash
helloworld:x:1004:1004:,,,:/home/helloworld:/bin/bash
crashdebug:x:1005:1000:,,,:/home/crashdebug:/bin/bash
```

I have no idea what is going on here. Maybe the problem is sd card corruption because `/etc/group-` is filled with binary dump and `/var/log/auth.log` to a great extent too.
Anyway, apart the above problems, the Raspberry still works without much issues, though I would not dare to restart it.
User `pi` is still sudoer, though it belongs only to group `crashdebug` which is not sudoer (tested), even after re-logging/re-sshing `pi` is still sudoer, how is it possible ???

Has anybody any idea how to address this issue ?

Comment: Can you show some of your `/etc/passwd` that includes them?

Comment: You seem to have two choices. 1) live with the uncertainty of not knowing when you might lose important data, or 2) re-flash the SD card and be more careful in future.

Comment: @Joan that's actually a lovely answer! I'd accept it. <3

Comment: @SDsolar question edited. Also included all created users. `adminmiaou` is no more sudoer but `pi` still is.

Comment: All good.  I agree that backing up your SD card would be a very good idea before proceeding.  Here's a good way to do it using Win32DiskImager:  https://www.howtogeek.com/341944/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-card-for-foolproof-backup/

Comment: I finally lost contact with outland raspberry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation continued to deteriorate till I could no more ssh (connection refused). It appears that simply unplugging and replugging the raspi finally solved the issue. The files where restored to a state prior to inconsistencies and prior to my latest modifications of sshd_config, so authentication through `allowgroups` was back ! I guess the restart triggered `fsck` and it seems now quite sure that a simple reboot through ssh when it was still working would have do the trick, anyway I did not dare to do this.